# How to find angle of reflected Ray to match a Point

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, trigonometry

this is for a Tank game I am making

Please see pic for a clear idea :[link text](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/2891/tank2.jpg)

I want to precompute the exacte angle to hit Point T2.

T1:point start

T2:point Target

V1(a,b):line

reflect point : this is what I m looking for :)

Edit:it would be cool to see some  "Code" :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'd be useful to see what happens to lines/vectors during reflection.  Wikipedia provides a nice picture for this:

[image: reflection]

Where, in this picture, in a proper reflection, **both angles are the same**.

Now, what does that have to do with you?  Let's take a look again at your situation.

[image: fancy diagram]

Note that, due to the laws of reflection, the angles `a` and `b` are equal.  That's good for us, because if we know that, we know `c` and `d` are also equal! (They are right triangles)

So we know:

```
a = b
c = d
```

We soon realize that we have **similar triangles**.  Meaning, the corresponding sides are **proportional** to eachother.  Meaning, mathematically:

```
A / C = B / D
A / B = C / D
A / (A+B) =  B / (A+B) = C / P = D / P
```

So, if you know `A` and `B`, which you should, you can find your **reflection point** by adding `C` to the x value of the intersection.

You can find C this way:

```
Given:
  A (distance from shooting tank to wall)
  B (distance from target tank to wall)
  P (x distance between points)
Find:
  C (x distance from shooting tank where wall is to be hit)

A / (A+B) = C / P
C = A*P / (A+B)   <- here it is
```

For example, if your first tank is at `(1,5)` and your second tank is at `(3,7)`, and your wall is the x axis:

```
A = 5
B = 7
P = 3-1 = 2

therefore:
C = 5*2 / (5+7)
  = 10/12
  = 5/6
```

So your tank should shoot towards `(0,5/6)` if it wants to hit a tank at `(3,7)`.

For a more general solution:

```
if the wall is the X axis, and you have shooting tank at (s_x,s_y)
  and hit tank at (h_x,h_y), the point to be shot at is:

[ s_x + s_y * (h_x-s_x) / (h_y + s_y), 0 ]
```

---

## Alternative, with arbitrary wall placement/direction

The problem with the above solution is that your wall has to be your x axis.  What if it's not?

First, you need to find the distance from each point to the wall -- `A` and `B`:

1. Find `w`, which is the [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_Vector) in the direction of the wall.
2. From `w`, find `v`, which is the unit vector perpendicular to the wall.  If `w = [x,by]`, `v = [-y,x]`.
3. Find `r_s`, which is the vector from your shooting tank to any known point on your wall.
4. Find `r_h`, which is the vector from your hit tank to any known point on your wall.
5. The distance `A = | v . r_s |`, where `.` is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_Product) operator.  This can be found by `[l,m] . [n,o] = l*n + m*o`
6. The distance `B = | v . r_h |`

Once you find `A` and `B`, find `P`, which is the distance parallel to the wall.  To do that:

1. Find `q`, which is the vector from the hit tank to the shooting tank
2. The distance `P = | w . q |`

Now that you have `A`, `B`, and `P`, you have two ways to go:

1. Find the point on the wall to aim for, by first solving for C in the method above and then finding the intersection of `v` starting from your shooting tank and your wall, and adding `C*w` to that intersection point.
2. You can find the angle (from `v`) that you must shoot, and it's the inverse tangent of `P/(A+B)`.

Comment: thanx Justin..
if you have any resource " code or pseudocode" would be nice to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Reflect T2 on the other side of V1, using V1 as the axis of reflection (we'll call this new point T2'); The line between T1 and T2' will intersect V1 at the point you want. From that point it's a matter of simple trigonometry to figure out what any angles are.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_%28geometry%29#Reflection

Comment: thanx JAB.I'm going to see if I can implement this...and looking for other responses.